# Cognito credentials have via Facebook has stopped working. Is my token truly expired?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have been writing a proof of concept, where a user logs in with facebook and i use that token to get cognito credentials.

I had it working and it has stopped.

Trying to figure it out and i see `expired:true` in my object log statement.

I can't see any settings in my facebook app or identity pool that would cause this, i didn't change anything.

CODE:

```
AWS.config.region = "us-east-1";
AWS.config.update({
        credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
          IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:8fd8.....',
          Logins: {
          'graph.facebook.com': userService.getFbToken()
          },
        })
      });

      $log.info(AWS.config.credentials);

      s3 = new AWS.S3();
```

LOG MESSAGE:

```
NotAuthorizedException: Missing credentials in config
```

OBJECT CONTENT:

```
CognitoIdentityCredentials {expired: true, expireTime: null, accessKeyId: undefined, sessionToken: undefined, params: Object…}
accessKeyId:undefined
cognito:features.constructor
data:null
expireTime:null
expired:true
identityId:null
params:
Object
IdentityPoolId:"us-east-1:8fd8....."
Logins:
Object
graph.facebook.com:
"CAAFJdF1QKZBYBAKrTetOsBczjINTF......."
__proto__:
Object
RoleSessionName:"web-identity"
```

Am I truly expired?  I just logged in as a test.  I mentioned my app before, I was wondering if something was wrong with the setup?

Any suggestions?

UPDATE 2016-09-06:
I have abandoned this, as it became not worth the effort for what I was doing.  If I ever return to it and figure it out, I will update again.

Comment: What happens if you do: AWS.config.credentials.get() then log the credentials object?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? i am struggling with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issues that my facebook AWS cognito stopped working all the sudden and gave me the error "NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. Token is expired.". I spent a couple of days looking through forums and couldn't find the cause for the error in my code. Finally, the problem is fixed when I created a new Facebook App and change my FB app id. I think it has something to do with your facebook app setting, maybe it is a test app which was the case for me.